# Error when trying to link two sharepoint lists together via Workflow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I populate a record in List A (R.O.W) (which I expected), the workflow says Error and in List B(District ROW Tracking).

Instead of one record being populated of List A (R.O.W), it creates 7 records.

What did I do wrong? Also both columns in both lists are the exact same name.

Below is the workflow I did, each line contains the column name I want to copy over to List B (District ROW)
[image]

2nd images is Instead of showing the cloned record, it displays 7 new records I am not sure WHY!

and the 3rd images is the error that occurred.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why you are doing 7 `Copy Item` instead you just need only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just one 'Copy Item' action in your workflow.

In the 'Choose list item' dialog, you have an option of selecting just one column and the value to uniquely identify the item you wish to copy (all columns will be copied regardless).
I would suggest using the ID column for this.

This should solve the 7 times copy issue.